# Make Commerce Kickstart home page show up at a different URL

Tags: commerce, path-aliases

By default, the store is the front page in Commerce Kickstart.  I want to have a different page as the front page, but be able to switch to Commerce Kickstart by clicking on a menu link.  However, when I change the front page to be my welcome page in Site Information, the store is no longer accessible.  How do I link the front store page to a link in a menu?  Essentially, I want the commerce kickstart store to be accessible from http://homepage/store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `front` page on Commerce Kickstart is `node`. The content is defined via blocks. So if you want to change the front page to another page, you could create a page and set it as the `front` page in the admin. None of the blocks should show up. If you want to make the contents of the current `node` page visible on a new or custom page, then you'll need to change the block configuration of all of the blocks that are currently visible on `node` and configure them to show up on another page.

Comment: Ultimately what I did was create a Basic page with the url alias store.  I made sure that the product catalog and the shopping cart showed up on that page by adding store* to the pages that those blocks were to show up on.  I then changed the front page to be another content page.  I was then able to access the store via <mywebsite>/store.  This is very similar to what you suggested so I will accept your answer.